# spring jpa not creating table spring mvc

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a spring mvc app where I am using Spring JPA to make tables and connect to database.Initially my JPA was working and tables were also getting created but due to some debugging issues I dropped all the tables and when I again ran the API it is not creating the tables anymore and giving me this error:

```
ERROR: relation "clients" does not exist\n  Position: 449
2021-07-27 15:33:50 [@] ERROR GenericControllerAdvice: Exception StackTrace:
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:424) ~[spring-orm-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:526) ~[spring-orm-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
```

My JPA configs are:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test?createDatabaseIfNotExists=true" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="" />

    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.clients" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ddl-auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="generate-ddl">true</prop>
        </props>
        </property>
```

I have created the test database and its has default 1 public schema.
Can someone help?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot or not?

Comment: using spring mvc

Answer (score 1):

The Hibernate properties are wrong.

It must be:

```
<props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
</props>
```